# Show that a projection is continuous by using a norm

Tags: vector-spaces, continuity

Let $E$ be a vector space of all continuous functions $f\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$. Let $F$ be a subspace of $E$ that contains all functions $f$ in $E$ that have a continuous first derivative $f’$ in $]0,1[$ and so that $f’$ extends as a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

We have a norm on $E$, $\|f\|_\inf = \sup_{0\le x\le1} |f(x)|$. On $F$ we have two norms $\|f\|_\inf $ and $\|f\|_1 = \|f\|_\inf + \|f’\|_\inf$.

And finally we have a linear projection $T\colon F\to E$ given by $T(f)=f’$.

(i) Show that $T$ is continuous projection if we use the norm $\|f\|_1$ in $F$.

(ii) Show that $T$ is not continuous projection if we use the norm $\|f\|_\inf $ in $F$.

I know that a projection is continuous at a point $a$ if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exist $\delta >0$ such that $d_Y(f(x),f(a))<\epsilon$ for all $x\in X$ that meet $ d_X(x,a)<\delta$.

And than a projection is continuous if it’s continuous at every point $a$.

But I’m not really sure how to use the norms in this and where.

I was doing something like this to show it’s continuous at some $a$.

$f_n \rightarrow v$, then $\|f_n \rightarrow v\|\rightarrow a$

so  $f_n-v\rightarrow a$

Than we get $T(f_n-v)\rightarrow a$

$T(f_n)-T(v)\rightarrow a$

$T(f_n)\rightarrow a-T(v)$

But I don’t know if that’s enough and I don’t think I’m even using the norms so I’m pretty lost. If anyone has some ideas it would really help.

Comment: $T$ is _not_ a projection.

Comment: But it’s given in the example that it’s a projection

Comment: It really doesn't matter whether or not $T$ is a projection in showing $T$ is continuous. But it's not. Saying $T$ is a projection means that $T^2=T$; that would say $f''=f'$...

Comment: Probably, "linear projection" (which is wrong in this case) is supposed to be "linear operator"? The definition of continuity stated in the OP just confirms that that's what is meant in the question.

Comment: And to be honest, I don't understand what you wrote as your attempt at a proof. None of these statements -- "then $\|f_n\to v\|\to a$" and "so $f_n-v\to a$" and "then we get $T(f_n-v)\to a$" and "$T(f_n)-T(v)\to a$" and "$T(f_n)\to a-T(v)$" -- make much sense. What is that mysterious $a$ that appears in all these statements?